# Select data with IF condition and IF data not found then insert data with last inserted data + 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
1.Select data from table
2.If data not found then insert data into that table with last record data using + 1
Table name = demo
Query = Select * from demo where user_id = test4 if not then insert into demo values ('test4','port1+1','port2+1','port3+1','port4+1');
```

Example :

```
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
| id | user_id                        | port1     | port2  | port3  | port4 |
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | test1                          | 27        | 72     | 58     | 65   |
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

I need output like this:

```
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
| id | user_id                        | port1     | port2  | port3  | port4 |
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | test1                          | 27        | 72     | 58     | 65   |
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
|  2 | test4                          | 28        | 73     | 59     | 66   |
+----+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: What is the query to select the data from the first step?

Comment: @Jaykishan Solanki : Did the answer I posted work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct and my first try would be,

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    port1 int,
    port2 int,
    port3 int,
    port4 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into demo(user_id,port1,port2,port3,port4)
values('Test1',10,20,30,40),
('Test2',100,200,300,400)
```

---

```
insert into demo(user_id,port1,port2,port3,port4)
select 'Test4',port1+1,port2+1,port3+1,port4+1
  from demo
 where user_id != 'Test4'
   and not exists (select 1 from demo where user_id = 'Test4')
order by id desc
limit 1
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3681b668964c6a0a7c62a85bf64290b9)